# enter-pssession : Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The user name or password is incorrect

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am unable to connect to domain controller via below script. This script is working for another domain controller so it mean script is correct. While I am connecting i am getting an error:

```
enter-pssession : Connecting to remote server "COMPUTER Name" failed with the following error message : The user name or
password is incorrect. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I am 100 % sure my credentials are correct and if I type manually I can connect (PSsession) to domain .

SCRIPT -

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "<MyPassword>" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("<Domain\UserName>", $password)
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <IPAddress> -Port <PortNumber> -Credential $cred
```

WinRM service is working. `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts *` is also applied.

Comment: Can you try this and tell me what happens? Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <IPAddress> -Port <PortNumber> -Credential (Get-Credential)

Comment: i already have tried this , this is prompting for credentials and i can successfully connect to domain controller. 
but i want to connect through script . can you help me

Comment: Interesting. If passing credentials via Get-Credential works, your script should work as well. I see no reason why it would fail.

Comment: :) you are right this is happening ...let me login through domain admin ...then see

Comment: I have the same issue -- Get-Credential works, but using the PSCredential + SecureString does not.  Who knows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and  helped me
[https://migration-tool.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000640868-Hide-credentials-in-scripts][1]

I created password using long string which i get from

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
ConvertFrom-SecureString $credentials.Password
```

Then I converted it to credentials using

```
$secureString = "01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000c57ba489a6781343983ef0deba79d0250000000002000000000003660000c0000000100000007ba4ea450748178832c0187a37c513270000000004800000a000000010000000a3fe44ced5ac805a2fcf7a6c3652994510000000ccc7701593bd519546d09f216962fac4140000003904619dc8c320b7fb0cafa6efdd78dd2c69c8e5"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $secureString
$UserName = employee@sharegate.com
```

I passed it to Invoke-Command like that

```
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
     -ArgumentList $UserName, $password  
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {whoami} -ErrorAction Stop
```